# accessing data of one class in another using friend function

Tags: c++, object

i made the following code where data and process are two classes and i m trying to use the variables of the object of data class in the functions of process class by making them friend to the data class.

```
class data;
class process
{
 public:
    void rarea(data ob);

    void carea(data ob);

};
void process::rarea(data ob)
{
    int a;
    a=ob.l*ob.b;
    cout<<a;
}
void process::carea(data ob)
{
    int a;
    a=3.14*ob.r*ob.r;
    cout<<a;

}
class data
{
    int l,b,r;

public:
    void input()
    {
        cin>>l>>b>>r;
    }
    friend void process::carea(data);
    friend void process::rarea(data);

};


int main()
{
    data d;
    process p;
    d.input();
    p.carea(d);
    p.rarea(d);
}
```

but the compiler is giving errors.

error:'ob' has incomplete type

error:forward declaration of data

Comment: The compiler needs to know how the `data` class is defined before you can use it - simply forward-declaring it as a class isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of `rarea` and `carea` need access to the definition of `data`, or they won't know what one looks like.

Their declarations don't, so it will work if you just rearrange a little:

```
class data;

class process
{
 public:
    void rarea(data ob);
    void carea(data ob);
};

class data
{
    int l,b,r;

public:
    void input()
    {
        cin>>l>>b>>r;
    }
    friend void process::carea(data);
    friend void process::rarea(data);
};

void process::rarea(data ob)
{
    //...
}

void process::carea(data ob)
{
    //...    
}
```